# Using XQuery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, xquery

I'm trying to retrieve information from an Oracle database using XQuery.
The table `customer` looks like

```
---id---last_name---
   1    Smith
   2    Jackson
   3    Peters
```

and I want all last names.
This is my code:

```
select last_name, XMLQuery(
'for $i in /customer
return $i/last_name'
PASSING BY VALUE customer
RETURNING CONTENT) last_name
FROM customer;
```

It says, there is an `%s: invalid identifier` in this line: `PASSING BY VALUE customer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use XQuery to query purely relational data.

In that case, you can use [ora:view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_xquery.htm#autoId19) and something such as:

```
SELECT XMLQuery('
    for $customer in ora:view("customer")/ROW
       return $customer/LAST_NAME
' RETURNING CONTENT) FROM DUAL;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `ora:view` embeds each row in a `ROW` element.

Comment: Is it also possible to select only particular columns to show?